# Change or figure out what the stat structure uses for block size in C?

Tags: c, struct, posix, stat

As listed here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html

The stat structure provides a block count and a block size. When I print

```
printf("BLOCK COUNT: %ju\n", statp->st_blocks);
```

It returns a higher value than `ls -ls` does. (In other words, it's using a smaller block size.)

In particular, it's using 512 bytes, because if I do `ls -ls --block-size=512`, I get the same result.

However, when I do:

```
printf("BLOCK SIZE: %ju\n", statp->st_blksize);
```

I get `1048576`.

Is there a way to programmatically get the block size used in the st_blocks variable, or change the one it uses (one or the other is fine)?

Comment: That `j` size modifier doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: That link says: "The unit for the *st_blocks* member of the **stat** structure is not defined within IEEE Std 1003.1-2001. In some implementations it is 512 bytes. It may differ on a file system basis. There is no correlation between values of the *st_blocks* and *st_blksize* [...] structure members."

Comment: The Linux `stat` man page documents `st_blocks` to be in 512 byte units.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX documentation has this to say:

> There is no correlation between values of the `st_blocks` and `st_blksize`, and the `f_bsize` (from `<sys/statvfs.h>`) structure members.

The latter concerns the block size for the file system itself. The `st_blksize` member is documented as the *preferred* block size for the *file* object, rather than the file system, as per its description (my emphasis):

> A file system-specific preferred I/O block size for *this object.* In some file system types, this *may vary from file to file.*

*Possibly,* though this bit is speculation, it's meant as a way to let you know what block size you should be using if you need to process this file yourself.

For example, say you were on a filesystem that was meant primarily for fixed-record-length files. It's plausible that it may store the record length in the directory information so that, should you need to process it, the information would be available to you.

Now that may seem unlikely in a world where the vast majority of people just use the default (ext4?) file system, but there's nothing stopping someone from writing a heavily optimised file system for specific purpose - you can often wring more performance out of something by virtue of the fact you have specific knowledge of its properties, rather than just relying on generic stuff. In fact, I believe the ClearCase we used to use under HP-UX did something like that for their artefact storage.